# sending data from clicklistener to an activity using intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I have put a button click listener inside a custom adapter,and on click of that button ,i am opening an activity and sending some data to that activity through intent but its not getting the value and every time it takes zero.
here is my click listener.

```
comments.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int p=(Integer)upvote.getTag();
                Intent i = new Intent(ctx, Comments.class);
                i.putExtra("taskid",tasks.get(p)
                        .get_id());
                i.putExtra("torc",1);
                ctx.startActivity(i);
            }
```

and here is the activity which is getting those values

```
public class Comments extends Activity {
int taskid,torc;
Comments_DAO cd;
CAforComments ca;
SharedPreferences sf;
int userId;
ArrayList<String> s;
ArrayList<Comments_table> comments;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_comments);
    sf=this.getSharedPreferences("SP", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    comments = new ArrayList<Comments_table>();
     s = new ArrayList<String>();
    ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    cd = new Comments_DAO(this);
    Intent i = getIntent();
    i.getIntExtra("taskid", taskid);
    i.getIntExtra("torc", torc);
    Toast.makeText(this,""+taskid+" "+torc,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    comments = cd.getComments(taskid,torc);
    for(int i1=0;i1<comments.size();i1++)
        s.add("");
    ca = new CAforComments(this, comments, s);
    lv.setAdapter(ca);
}

public void comment(View view) {
    EditText et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    String s1 = new String();
    s1 = et1.getText().toString();
    Comments_table ct=cd.createComment(s1,sf.getInt("userId",userId),torc,taskid);
    et1.setText("");
    comments.add(ct);
    s.add("");
    ca.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change these

```
Intent i = getIntent();
i.getIntExtra("taskid", taskid);
i.getIntExtra("torc", torc);
```

to

```
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();     
taskid= b.getInt("taskid");
torc= b.getInt("torc");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
i.getIntExtra("taskid", taskid);
i.getIntExtra("torc", torc);
```

change to

```
taskid=i.getIntExtra("taskid", taskid);
torc=i.getIntExtra("torc", torc);
```